# Pandas : Changing a column of dataset from string to integer

Tags: python, pandas

One Column of my dataset is like this:

```
0        10,000+
1       500,000+
2     5,000,000+
3    50,000,000+
4       100,000+
Name: Installs, dtype: object
```

and I want to change these 'xxx,yyy,zzz+' strings to integers.
first I tried this function:

```
df['Installs'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Installs'])
```

and I got this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "10,000" at position 0
```

and then I tried to remove '+' and ',' with this method:

```
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].str.replace('+','',regex = True)
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].str.replace(',','',regex = True)
```

but nothing changed!

How can I convert these strings to integers?

Comment: Don't use `regex=True`, but `regex=False`, or use a correct regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is not a valid regex, use:

```
df['Installs'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Installs'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm too slow typing on a phone :p

Answer (score 3):

With `regex=True`, the `+` (plus) character is interepreted specially, as a regex feature. You can either disable regular expression replacement (`regex=False`), or even better, change your regular expression to match `+` or `,` and remove them at once:

```
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].str.replace('[+,]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df['Installs']
0       10000
1      500000
2     5000000
3    50000000
4      100000
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Maybe. I have to increase my typing speed (and my English level). lol

Comment: I think you're proficient enough! You somehow answer more questions a day, it seems, than I do. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯